# Select rows from a dataframe that have specific element names

Tags: r, function, subset

I have a dataframe with more than 100 columns, I wanted to know how I can subset or select rows that have a specific element name without writing all 100 column names in the subset function.

Example data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,                       
                   x2 = c("ab", "9", "bc", 6, 7),
                   x3 = c(8, "ab", 10, "cd", "ef"),
                   x4 = c(11, 12, "ij", "gh", "ab"))
data

#x1 x2 x3 x4
#1  1 ab  8 11
#2  2  9 ab 12
#3  3 bc 10 ij
#4  4  6 cd gh
#5  5  7 ef ab`

#Select rows that have the element name "ab".

subset(data, x1 == "ab" | x2 == "ab" | x3 == "ab" | x4 == "ab")

#x1 x2 x3 x4
#1  1 ab  8 11
#2  2  9 ab 12
#5  5  7 ef ab
```

How can I subset or select rows that have a specific element name without writing all 100 column names in the subset function?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) one-liner:

```
dplyr::filter(data, if_any(everything(), ~ . == "ab"))
```

Comment: @rhay generally speaking on StackOverflow we upvote and mark questions as answered, but it's your choice what you do

Comment: I am sorry since i am not used to the process. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to filter rows using base R's `rowSums`.

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,                       
                   x2 = c("ab", "9", "bc", 6, 7),
                   x3 = c(8, "ab", 10, "cd", "ef"),
                   x4 = c(11, 12, "ij", "gh", "ab"))

# base-r one-liner
data[rowSums(data == 'ab') > 0,]
```

output:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  1 ab  8 11
2  2  9 ab 12
5  5  7 ef ab
```